# Run single wct test through gulp task

Tags: javascript, gulp, web-component-tester

How do I have to create a single gulp task to run a single wct test? I have the following project structure:

```
|-build
|--gulpfile.babel.js
|--wct.conf.js
|-test
|--test-folder1
|----t-test1.html
|----t-test1.js
|--test-folder2
|----t-test2.html
|----t-test2.js
```

Inside my **gulpfile.babel.js** I would like to create separate tasks for `t-test1` and `t-test2`.

Pseudo code:

```
gulp.task('test1', (done) => { 
    <RUN WCT TEST FROM FOLDER t-folder1>; // Is there a way to trigger single test here???
    done();
});

gulp.task('test2', (done) => { 
    <RUN WCT TEST FROM FOLDER t-folder2>; // Is there a way to trigger single test here???
    done();
});
```

I couldn't find any sample code for this.

Any help is appreciated.